# PDO PHP MYSQL OOP Advice and How to

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop, pdo

let me explain what I'm trying to do.

1. I've made a db.config.php file that contains all the database details and establishes a connection.
2. I've made another db.connect.php file which only establishes a connection by calling the function to make connection in db.config file, thus only difference between the two files is that db.config.php contains connection info like dbname etc while db.connect.php does not.
3. What I want to do is that now everywhere I need to make a connection to database it should be done using db.connect.php file.
4. Is what I'm doing secure and a proper way to do things?
5. The code is as follows

   ### db.config.php

   ```
   <?php
   class Database{
   private $DB_host = 'localhost';
   private $DB_name = 'db_pdo';
   private $DB_user = 'root';
   private $DB_pass = 'secret';
   public $conn;

   public function makeConnection(){
       $this->conn = null;
       try{
           $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->DB_host.";dbname=".$this->DB_name,$this->DB_user,$this->DB_pass);
       }
       catch(PDOException $e){
           echo "Connection error:- ".$e->getMessage();
       }
       return $this->conn;
   }
   ```

   }

### db.connect.php

```
    <?php
    include_once 'db.config.php';
    class Connect{
    public $database;
    public $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->makeConnection();

        if($db){
            return $db;
        }
        else{
            echo "Connection Failed";
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I want is if suppose I make a new PHP file with Class say Test,
How do I go about making connection using only the db.connect.php file?

Does this really add a extra level of security to the application as I was told?

Also if what I'm doing is unnecessary please tell me so.
Thank you.

Comment: Extra security relative to what? The database credentials are still accessible from within any other script (which afaik is unavoidable anyway).

Answer (score 2):

This is complete overkill. You instantiate two classes with the only result being a PDO object, the classes Connect and Database aren't used anymore after that. You can remove them completely and use only these lines with the same result:

```
$DB_host = 'localhost';
$DB_name = 'db_pdo';
$DB_user = 'root';
$DB_pass = 'secret';
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$DB_host .";dbname=".$DB_name,$DB_user,$DB_pass);
```

Include this file and use `$db` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include `db.connect.php` every time you want to connect to the db.

No it is not adding any level of security, it is more about reusability, Say if you wanted to change the password, you will just change it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this really add a extra level of security to the application as I was told?

No it doesn't. As a matter of fact it doesn't add anything besides needless complexity.

There are numerous ways to retrieve the (`private`) credentials once I can run code on the machine.

Just create the `PDO` object when needed first and pass it around to thing that need it. Wrapping `PDO` in extra classes like above is useless.

Also considering this question is tagged OOP:

You should always try to prevent creating instances (using the `new` keyword in most cases) inside other classes as this introduces tight coupling and makes unit testing your code harder because of this.

> Is what I'm doing secure and a proper way to do things?

Proper not so much as outlined above.

Secure, well it depends what you are trying to prevent and what the rest of your set up looks like (e.g. no sensitive files in your doc root etc). But it terms of security your shared code doesn't really do much (if anything at all).

Finally your constructor of the `Connect` class tries to return something `$db` which doesn't make any sense. The constructor always returns an instance of itself.

What does may help security is using real proper prepared statements instead of the emulated ones used by default when setting up a PDO instance using the mysql engine. To do it set the correct options:

```
$dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=".$DB_host.";dbname=".$DB_name.";charset=utf8",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Also note that I have also set the encoding used for the connection.

The actual settings for the db connection could be saved in some config file somewhere either as environment variables of the webserver or as a config file somewhere *outside* the document root.